# How to check if an uialertview has been dismissed?

Tags: uialertview, status, nslog

in my program I have two ways to dismiss an uialertview: one by button click and one by nstimer. If the button is clicked before the timer fires my program quits when the timer fires. How do I check the status of the uialertview so that the timer knows whether or not to execute a dismiss message? And what NSLog statement should I use for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're app is crashing with an exception because you got stale pointer to the deallocated `UIAlertView`. I guess that you're not resetting the instance variable that references the `UIAlertView`.

You surely got an instance variable to save the UIAlertView pointer. You also need to set the [`delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertView/delegate) property, like this:

```
myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
myAlert.delegate = self;
[myAlert show];
// Now setup the timer
```

Your class must implement the [UIAlertViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007548), specifically you need to implement `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:` and/or `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` (I'd use the later). In this method, you reset the instance variable:

```
[myAlert release];
myAlert = nil;
// Also cancel timer
```

Canceling the timer isn't *that* important any more as setting the variable to `nil` is the  important part. Once the timer would fire it wouldn't crash any more (but canceling the timer would still be a good idea).